# Printing a list using list(range(x)) instead of range(x)

Tags: python, python-3.x

This might seem like a trivial question, but it seemed non-intuitive to me that `list(range(5))` would print the contents of the list: `[0,1,2,3,4]`. I was thinking that `range(5)` would suffice. Is there a reason for this?

Is this merely because the function definition of `list()` prints out the contents while converting any non-list arguments (such as a range)?

P.S. As my intent is to print contents of a list I'm aware there are other methods. Having to use `list()` was just a bit of a surprise so I thought to ask.

Comment: `range(x)` does not produce a `list`, it produces a `range` object. Indeed, `range` is just the class, just like `list`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: More details [in the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges)